# Will I pay tax in Germany on money sent to me by my friend who lives in the US?

Tags: taxes, germany, gift-tax

A friend wants to send me money as a gift to help me with a few of my plans, my friend lives in the US, and I live in Germany (Berlin).

Will I have to pay any tax on this money? Do I need to declare this to any authority (IRS or German authority)?

If not, then how much can I receive per year?

Comment: This might help: https://www.taxexpense.com/germany-taxes/germany-inheritance-estate-tax/

Comment: Is this a legitimate gift?  In which case your friend has no expectation of ever getting any money back no matter how successful your plans are?  Or is is a loan and/or an investment where your plan is to start a business and your friend expects to at least get his money back at some point in the future if your business is successful?

Comment: It is a scam. You will go to jail for money laundering.

Comment: It is a gift, my friend won't get their money back whatsoever, I don't know what I'll do with the money as it's a gift, I'll probably buy a PS5 or something!


And why would it be a scam or money laundering?

Comment: Thanks a lot @RonJohn, I'm gonna spend some time today and read this article you shared, looks like it will have all the answers!